# "Error on Authentication Error: Network Error" in React authentication API call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have made a authenticated API call..below my code is there i am getting "Error on Authentication Error"

```
 componentDidMount()
{
    let config = {'Authorization': 'Here i have pasted the auth key from Post mAN'};

          axios.get('http://XX.XX.XX.XX/aa/bb/cc/list', { headers: config })

          .then(function(response) {
            console.log('Authenticated');
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error on Authentication' + error);
          })

}
```

Comment: Dont you miss there `'auhtorization' : bearer  ' auth key '`

Answer (score 1):

You may have send `Authorization` with `Bearer`. Do this way.

```
let config = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ key};
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of authorization. If token authorization use

`` let config = {'Authorization': `Token ${key}`}; ``